# Error in using UIAutomatorviewer for testing Android app in Appium

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I have to automate an Android application, I am doing the same through Appium.

The problem I am facing is after launching the Appium server, the app is getting installed in the emulator 4.4.2.  To inspect the element I am using `UIAutomatorviewer` which comes default with SDK. But while inspecting the element of the app, I am getting the error:

```
Error obtaining UI hierarchy
Reason:Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file.com.android.ddmlb.SynchException.Remote object doesn't exist.
```

I tried to find the solution so that I can inspect the element so that I can script, but in vain.

1. Can someone please tell how to fix the issue so that I can inspect elements?
2. Is there any other way I can inspect element in the app apart from using `UIAutomator` viewer?

Answer (score 31):

After my tryst with the uiautomator viewer i came to know that we get the error only when:

appium server is running and we try to capture the screenshot using uiautomatorviewer.

So, whenever you want to use uiautomatorviewer make sure that server is in stopped state.

Comment: This is definitely the most common reason. A quick command-line way to kill appium servers is `taskkill /F /IM node.exe` (warning: will kill all node servers). However, for the case where no Appium server was running, the answer below worked better for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28526871/682912

Comment: It didnt helped in my case, I have stopped the Appium server though

Answer (score 12):

I fixed the same issue by using following methods.

(1) Connect your Android device to your development machines;

(2) Go to command line in terminal or DOS command line for Windows;

(3) Using "adb shell" into your Android devices;

(4) Change the user to root by input "su root" in command line;

(5) Change the access right to /data/local/tmp by input "chmod 777 /data/local/tmp";

(6) Go back to uiautomatorviewer and do screen shot again, the error should be gone;

I guess there are some file can't be access if it doesn't own right in /data/local/tmp.

Comment: when I tried to follow it I just got "/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found" after step 4

Answer (score 11):

Make sure everything on your screen is static. And flashing input cursor is also not allowed. Any painting actions will stop uiautomator from dumping current UI.

You can test by using following adb command:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump /data/local/tmp/uidump.xml
```

if the message `ERROR: could not get idle state.` appears, you are suffering from this issue.

See lines 87 & 101 of [`DumpCommand`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/jb-mr2-release/uiautomator/cmds/uiautomator/src/com/android/commands/uiautomator/DumpCommand.java):

> ```
> try {
>   ...   
>   uiAutomation.waitForIdle(1000, 1000 * 10);
>   ...
> } catch (TimeoutException re) {
>   System.err.println("ERROR: could not get idle state.");
>   return;
> }
> ```

Comment: Yep, I was getting the same error. And I observed that timer is running on particular screen. When I stopped the timer. It work like a charm.

Comment: I got that idle state error but not sure how to resolve it because I don't have access to the source code of the app under test so I can't disable timers etc.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest solution..

Restart the device. Restart uiautomatorviewer.

Worked like a charm for me .... :P

Answer (score 4):

Stop the Appium Server. Then try again. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question **#2**
You can inspect Android app directly from your real Android device.

You need to:

- Connect Android device to your computer/laptop
- Go to Android device Settings -> Enable *Developer Options* and *Android debbuging*

Please see here:
[image: Android device settings]

- Start the app you wish to inspect in your Android device
- Open up the Chrome browser on your computer/laptop and do a right click -> More Tools -> Inspect devices -> Click on your device -> (Click on Android device `OK` to authorize) -> Click `Inspect`

Please see here: [image: Inspect whatever from your Android device]

That's it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Is this perhaps CyanogenMod specific? Or root required? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I used "adbd insecure". So I just disabled "adbd insecure", and reload uiautomatorviewer, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

In case of rooted devices: Enable the root access in developer options for adb. Restart adb as root

Answer (score 1):

I have spent over a week to resolve this issue. When you connect your device and using ASM 3.0, when  screen is projected open the UIAutomator to capture the current android screen. Without Appium it should capture. For use Android Studio instead of android sdk. Uninstall and reinstall Android Studio. It is working perfect for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I got also the same issue (Also if Appium Server was not running). After switch, OFF / ON USB-Debugging was working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved

I closed the Appium Server running on my machine and opened it again.
Later open uiautomater, and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The one that works is in this path:

```
Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```

Paste this in your terminal and it will run automator that works

Answer (score 0):

we have to use device which has API level morethan 17 or jelly bean

Answer (score 0):

Way to bypass the  ERROR:

> could not get idle state.

By using uiautomator to get uix and screenshot.

```
public class DeviceMethods extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
public void dump(){


    try {
        getUiDevice().dumpWindowHierarchy("window_dump.uix") ;
        getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/data/local/tmp/window_dump.png"));


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

you need to create the uiautomator jar and push it to /data/local/tmp

use [this tutorial](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/) on how to use uiautomator

after you get the files just open them in uiautomatorviewer

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

stop appium 
open an emulator device (tested with Android 7.1.1)
go into settings > developer options > Enable view attribute inspection 
open a shell on the computer, cmd or terminal depending on your OS 
enter the following commands: 
adb shell 
su 
cd /data 
cd /local 
chmod 777 tmp

start uiautomatorviewer 
take an xml screenshot

"su chmod 777 /data/local/tmp" didnt work for me so I drilled down and it worked. 
I assume that you have to do this in an emulator and not a physical device unless the device is rooted. ¯ \ _ (ツ)_/¯

Lotsa Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because adb is using port and it's blocked by appium server.

I have found out best solution for this

Kill the adb.exe from taskbar processes and try launching uiautomatorviewer again

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enabled these under "developer options" in the phone.

1. Verify apps via USB
2. View attribute inspection
3. USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

1) stop appium Server

2) open an emulator device

3) go into settings > developer options > Enable view attribute inspection

4) developer options in invisible? Go into settings > Tap on About device/phone > Scroll down till the last option(Build number) > Continuously Tap on "Build number" for 7 times > you should get an Toast message "You're a developer" > come back from that screen > Go back into settings > Now you should see developer options Tap on it > Enable view attribute inspection

5) You should no more get this error message

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use appium inspector instead? You can download it and follow instructions from [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases)

Answer (score -1):

try switching Off and then ON the USB debugging option.. this work for me