# UI Automator:Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I am using default android emulator and trying to fetch field ids using UI Automator. However it stops saying following line when I try to capture screen:

```
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
```

[I have followed this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201743/error-in-using-uiautomatorviewer-for-testing-android-app-in-appium/25243843#comment56961162_25243843)
but no success.

I am testing android app using Appium and need ids for writing test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If using Genymotion along with it, then enable the "Take screenshot" option in settings and then restart the device()