# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while taking screenshot from UI Automation Viewer

Tags: android-studio, appium, ui-automation, android-sdk-manager

While taking a screenshot from UI Automation Viewer, getting the error--

> Error obtaining UI hierarchy  Reason: Unexpected error while obtaining
>   UI hierarchy Details: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Please note that Appium server is stopped (Application closed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in using UIAutomatorviewer for testing Android app in Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201743/error-in-using-uiautomatorviewer-for-testing-android-app-in-appium)

Comment: I checked that answer bro, its different. My appium server wasn't even started

Comment: Have you also tried the second answer of that linked question? Where the issue is related to incorrect permissions.

Comment: @ChukUltima, tried that too, still getting the same error. In the command prompt its displayed "E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the screenshot while the appium server is still running. If you're using 'cmd' press 'CTRL + C' to terminate the session. Or if you're using the desktop version of Appium, you can try stopping the the appium server by closing the application.

Comment: It not running bro, i made sure of that.

Comment: Are you using a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Android studio emulator

Comment: I'm sorry I can't seem to find a solution for this. Maybe use Android Device Monitor within the latest Android Studio version instead of UI Automation Viewer

Comment: It didn't work either bro, when I tried taking a screenshot with a new emulator, I got "E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2" in console and Error obtaining UI hierarchy Reason: Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy Details: null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Android Device Monitor within the latest Android Studio version instead of UI Automation Viewer

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/releases/tag/v0.0.12s

Add `androidscreencast-0.0.12s-executable.jar` to `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib`