# Unable to Inspect Object com.android.incallui.service.SecCallPopupService on Samsung J5

Tags: android, adb, appium, android-uiautomator, in-call

I have a problem that I think is related with Android permissions, however I need some of your expertise to confirm it.

I have testing the old Samgung J5(Not rooted) with Android 8.1.0, Appium 1.10.0 with UiAutomator2 and ADB 10.0.40 (In administration mode) on some Call Handling scenarios where I need to check if determined display elements (identity, call duration, hold activated, on transfer information, etc) are displayed to user. I have seen multiple solutions to do this task, inclusively using adb to do it, but lets focus only on this problem, using only the display elements (GUI).

Scenario, user receives call.

The com.android.incallui.service.SecCallPopupService comes into action:

[User receives call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVfAL.png)

When I try to inspect the com.android.incallui.service.SecCallPopupService window the Appium cannot found it:

[Appium Inpector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIPCg.png)

Neither on UiAutomatorViewer:

[UitAutomatorViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhyWC.png)

On Comment link (xml dump) you can seen the display elements that Appium, and UiAutomatorViewer can "see". Same result was obtained by using the command adb shell uiautomator dump /data/local/tmp/uidump.xml

After  that, I installed the Appium Studio and try out the Appium official "Inspector" and the result was:

[Appium Studio Object Spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a77Zs.png) with full access to all display elements. Very intriguim... after some research I found the following package com.experitest.uiautomator.test (running in background) was immediatelly installed on the device when I clicked on Object Spy feature and I think that is responsible to retrieve all the interface elements.

On comment link (logcat) Some logcat logs after doind object spy on Appium Studio:

Analysing the logcat we can see that Appium studios was requesting
{"response":"true","params":[],"command":"richDump"} and the package uses
some kind of node:android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNode. Maybe using something like the Acessibility Tree node to get the [elements](https://withintent.uncorkedstudios.com/tutorial-debugging-android-accessibility-818cfd361414)  ? I don't know...

I have read some similar questions on Stackoverflow but some solutions involves to root the device or using de ADB (its not an option), 
[Tryng to su root the device and chmod 777 /data/local/tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201743/error-in-using-uiautomatorviewer-for-testing-android-app-in-appium), but if it's really necessary, how then Appium Studio can read all display elements?

Do you know any other solution that allows me to get all interface elements without root the device? How can I call the "richDump"?

Thank You for you help.

Comment: The logcat -> https://pastebin.com/raw/pxsh59ad

Comment: Xml Dump ->https://pastebin.com/raw/A6XjSEaG